# How do I comment on a answer to a question?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where is the FAQ?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33331/where-is-the-faq)

I would like to comment on an answer to a question, but I don't see any button to enter a comment. I see other people have entered comments, why can't I? Do I need some more reputation points before I can comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 50 rep to leave a comment (except on meta).

See the [SO FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Except when it's a comment to answers on your own question